# Where will I be able to see the Lyrid meteor shower?

Tags: meteor

So supposedly the Lyrids meteor shower will take place between early morning April 16th to 22nd - correct me if I am wrong. I am aged 15 and am interested in skywatching, I just wondered will it be visible from the northern Hemisphere? Or will it be like the lunar eclipse and only be visible in the Western Hemisphere? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely be able to see this meteor shower. It will be in the north east from your viewpoint near the star vega.

http://www.astronomy.co.uk/skymap

http://earthsky.org/astronomy-essentials/earthskys-meteor-shower-guide

You may find these websites useful. If you're interested in amateur astronomy, there is free software for interactive star maps. I use one called stellarium. I'm also an amateur astronomer and I've learned so much with it. You may enjoy it as well.

Comment: Yeah, I use Stellarium also as recommended to me by another guy named Jeremy on this awesome forum. Just to check do you know what time it will be tonight? GMT?

Comment: Tonight I'm not sure. According to Google the best time to view from the UK is going to be 1100-2200 BST. Try a few Google searches. You might come up with something. I often do that when answering questions.

Comment: Because the shower spans multiple days, there won't be a special time on any day to see them. They will get more numerous as you get towards the middle of the range of dates, then the number of meteors will tail off as the period draws to a close

Comment: Actually, they will continue through to April 25/26 and the 22nd is expected to be the peak time : http://earthsky.org/astronomy-essentials/everything-you-need-to-know-lyrid-meteor-shower

Comment: Thanks Ryan, and you too Jeremy. I am currently keeping my eye out, I can currently see Mars and am awaiting the visibility of Saturn. I can't, as of yet, see Vega. However, I will continue to keep my eye out for it, in the hope of seeing a few meteors. I'll make sure to try and get some pictures on my DSLR - if I see any, of course. Thanks once again!

Comment: Also Jeremy, would you recommend this? http://www.telescopehouse.com/acatalog/Meade-StarNavigator-130mm-Reflector-Telescope-1.html

Comment: For questions off topic from the question you've posed, feel free to message me privately on G+ - http://gplus.to/fivey